# Регулярные выражения в python, как заменить текст?

Tags: python, django, регулярные-выражения, re

**test.txt**

```
SOME TEXT
INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['plugins.apps.PluginsConfig','orders.apps.OrderConfig']
SOME TEXT
```

Надо получить INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['plugins.apps.PluginsConfig','orders.apps.OrderConfig'] и потом заменить эту строчку на другую

```
tag = re.findall(r'INSTALLED_APPS_ADD+.*\W+', content)
print('tag ', tag.group(0))
>> INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['plugins.apps.PluginsConfig','orders.apps.OrderConfig']
```

1. почему это регулярное выражение берет нужную переменную с параметрами? там же регулярное выражение \W+, которое доложно брать до конца файла? или оно останавливается из-за перехода на новую строчку?
2. как вставить вместо этой переменной другую используя re.sup?
   например INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['new.data']

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Чем обусловлена именно такая регулярка?
Я бы что-то вроде такой: `INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = (\[.*\])` поместил бы. При условии, что всегда будет соблюдено данное форматирование.
Ваш вариант плох тем, что он совпадёт с такой строкой (возможно это и допустимо для Вашего случая):
`INSTALLED_APPS_ADDED_LAST_WEEK = ['plugins.apps.PluginsConfig','orders.apps.OrderConfig']` (это одна длинная строка)
Пример взят из головы, но он достаточно показателен.
В python не силён, от слова совсем, но [тут](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html#re.sub) описана функция для такой замены.
Суть в том, чтобы заменить то, что в скобках в моём примере, это будет (\1 или $1) на то, что вам надо.
Регулярки делают поиск до конца строки, если не указать обратного. Например такая: `INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = (\[.*\])\n.*` совпадёт со второй и третьей строкой из **test.txt** из примера, но не совпадёт с четвёртой, если бы она была в файле.
**UPD**
Можно пойти от обратного. Регулярка примет вид:
`(INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = )\[.*\]`

```py
import re
tagretString = "INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['sdfsdfsdfsdf]"
sting2 = re.sub(r'(INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = )\[.*\]', r'\1[some_new_args]', tagretString)
print(tagretString)
print(sting2)
```

Только Вам `some_new_args` нужно изменить на то, что Вам надо. Там скрее всего будет конкатенация строк. Прошу прощения за ужасный код, в питон не умею, но вроде работает:)
Вывод:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: tag = re.findall(r'INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = (\\[.*\\])', content) - ничего не возвращает

Comment: @JopaBoga Исправил ответ.

Comment: да, спасибо, работает

Answer (score 0):

```py
import re

content = """
DEBUG = True
INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['plugins.apps.PluginsConfig','orders.apps.OrderConfig']
SOME TEXT
"""
print('content', content, sep=':')

pattern = r'INSTALLED_APPS_ADD+.*\W+'
print('pattern', pattern, sep=':')

pasted_text = "INSTALLED_APPS_ADD = ['new.data']\n"
print('pasted_text', pasted_text, sep=':')

new_content = re.sub(pattern, pasted_text, content, 1)
print('new_content', new_content, sep=':')
```

Вывод:
[image: Вывод программы]